# Editing password in password manager

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, change-password

okay so I am trying to edit passwords in my password manager app. this is the function;

```
def edit_password(password):
        text3 = 'Password'
        password = pop_up(text3)

        insert_fields = ('UPDATE vault SET password = ?')

        cursor.execute(insert_fields, (password))
        db.commit()

        password_vault()
```

I call it using a button like so;

```
btn = Button(window, text='Edit', command=partial(edit_password, array[i][0]))
btn.grid(column=5, row=i+3, pady = 30, padx=30)
```

However, it is changing the entire password column.

Comment: Normallly,  updating a field of a single row requires a select statement of some sort.

Comment: You need to add a `WHERE` clause to specify which rows to update.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE statement without a WHERE clause will update all records in the table.

So you need something like:

```
UPDATE vault SET password = ? WHERE username = ?
```

assume `username` is the unique column of `vault` table.

---

Note that *storing plain text password is not recommended*.

Comment: When I try this way. I get this error. I have tried many different variations.  `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "e:\School\CNA 256\1pyCodePrac\PasswordVault.py", line 164, in edit_password
    cursor.execute(insert_fields, (password))
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 2, and there are 1 supplied. `

Comment: sorry for the sloppy lay out I am still learning how to use Stackoverflow

Comment: You need to pass two values, password and username in this example.